# Getting the created workbook name after copying worksheet from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I call and re-use the workbook that gets created after executing

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copythis").Copy
```

I can't use the activeWorkbook since the user will go back to the previous workbook that has the vba.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim wbNew As Workbook

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copythis").Copy

Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

MsgBox wbNew.Name
```

Even if the user goes back and selects something else, you can work with the new workbook using the `wbNew` object.

Answer (score 1):

The newly created workbook will always be at the end of workbook array. So you can use this also

```
Dim wbNew

set wbNew = Application.Workbooks(Application.Workbooks.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [`Worksheet.Copy Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy)

- When using your line of code, the newly created workbook becomes the active one.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testWithVariable()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copythis").Copy
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Debug.Print wb.Name
    wb.Saved = True
End Sub

Sub testWithoutVariable()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copythis").Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Debug.Print .Name
        .Saved = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub testWorksheetWithoutVariable()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("copythis").Copy
    With ActiveSheet
        Debug.Print .Parent.Name ' workbook
        Debug.Print .Name ' worksheet
        .Parent.Saved = True
    End With
End Sub
```